# Representing SQL results in single row - ending up with stair-steps

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have records in SQL (Server) that I'm trying to represent in a readable manner, but it's not coming out right... 
I'm using a case statement to pull the field values into separate fields, but get a stair-step in the results. The raw rows look like this:

```
w x y z a 
w x y z b 
w x y z c
```

Using a case statement, I'm coming up with is:

```
w x y z a     null  null 
w x y z null  b     null
w x y z null  null  c
```

What I'm trying to get is one row for these three records, like this:

```
w x y z a b c
```

[Link To SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a93a/1/0)

I've done a bunch of searching, but I think I'm just not using the right word to describe the problem... Any direction would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you want to join the last column from different tuples joined such that the first columns match? Probably naive, but you could imagine them as `w x y z a w x y z b w x y z c`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  VALUES ('w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a'),
         ('w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'b'),
         ('w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'c')
) AS t(w, x, y, z, col)
PIVOT (
  MAX(col) FOR col IN ([a], [b], [c])
) AS PivotTable
```

The above yields:

```
w   x   y   z   a   b   c
-------------------------
w   x   y   z   a   b   c
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/7233)

The above pivoting in SQL Server (and Oracle) is essentially short for the following equivalent query:

```
SELECT 
  w, x, y, z, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN col = 'a' THEN 'a' END) a,
  MAX(CASE WHEN col = 'b' THEN 'b' END) b,
  MAX(CASE WHEN col = 'c' THEN 'c' END) c
FROM (
  VALUES ('w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a'),
         ('w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'b'),
         ('w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'c')
) AS t(w, x, y, z, col)
GROUP BY w, x, y, z
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, without `PIVOT` or `CASE`–nothing wrong, of course, with these–, to be completed by choosing the row you want from the result. It is using self joins,

```
select * from
   (select x1.*, x2.valA as valA2, x3.valA as valA3  
    from foo x1 inner join foo x2 inner join foo x3
    on     x1.valA <> x2.valA
       and x1.valA <> x3.valA
       and x2.valA <> x3.valA) as x
order by valA, valA2, valA3
```

resulting in

```
+------+------+------+------+------+-------+-------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | valA | valA2 | valA3 |
+------+------+------+------+------+-------+-------+
| w    | x    | y    | z    | a    | b     | c     |
| w    | x    | y    | z    | a    | c     | b     |
| w    | x    | y    | z    | b    | a     | c     |
| w    | x    | y    | z    | b    | c     | a     |
| w    | x    | y    | z    | c    | a     | b     |
| w    | x    | y    | z    | c    | b     | a     |
+------+------+------+------+------+-------+-------+
```